# error: cannot find symbol [ERROR] package org.openqa.selenium.support.ui

Tags: maven, selenium, junit

I am new to Selenium. I am running this mvn clean install (my selenium tests are integrated with Junit and running with Maven).

I am getting - cannot find symbol package org.openqa.selenium.support.ui

I searched and understood that I need to have dependency in my pom.xml so that the jar will have this dependency.

I have the following dependencies in my pom.xml but still getting error, please let me know what could be the issue?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
           <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
               <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
              <version>2.4.0</version>
            </dependency>
     <dependency>
             <groupId>junit</groupId>
              <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
          <groupId> org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
```

error:

[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/test/itest/in-container/src/test/java/com/dc/checkoutUIstorefront/StorefrontPurchaseBase.java:[10,37] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  package org.openqa.selenium.support.ui
/home/test/itest/in-container/src/test/java/com/dc/checkoutUIstorefront/StorefrontPurchaseTest.java:[10,37] error: cannot find symbol

Comment: i suggest using newer version of selenium-java, current is 2.39.0, see if it helps.

Comment: The problem was there is no ExpectedConditions class in the 2.4.0 version instead there is ExpectedCondition class. I changed my code and it worked after that. But now I am getting a new error where firefox opens but it doesn't go the base URL.

Comment: When I run the tests using eclipse I get the following:
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:98)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:148)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:88)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:127)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxD

Comment: When I run using Mvn clean install I get

>[INFO] Building Checkout ProductUI Integration Tests In-Container 1.6-SNAPSHOT
>[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>[INFO]
>[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ checkoutProductUITestsInContainer ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/sprasad/p4ws/sprasad_checkout_main/product-checkout/test/itest/in-container

Comment: /src/main/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ checkoutProductUITestsInContainer ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ checkoutProductUITestsInContainer ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.

Comment: [INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ checkoutProductUITestsInContainer ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

Comment: [INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.6:test (default-test) @ checkoutProductUITestsInContainer ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/sprasad/p4ws/sprasad_checkout_main/product-checkout/test/itest/in-container/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.429 sec

Comment: Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.589s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Feb 14 10:21:11 PST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/161M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------